# ServiceStack, how to access business logic Pocos?

Tags: c#, http, rest, inversion-of-control, servicestack

Given the following service class in ServiceStack,

```
public class HelloWorldService: Service
{
    public string Get(HelloWorldRequest request)
    {
        return someOtherClassInstance;
    }
}
```

how would I access `someOtherClassInstance`? I am puzzled about what best practices are to return objects in specific states? I understand its easy to access static class objects from within HelloWorldService but how about other instances that hold state? I feel extremely hard pressed to believe the best solution is IoC. Any better ways? How can I pass in references to be used? Any suggestions and ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over thinking this. A `Service` in ServiceStack is just a plain C# instance that gets initiated and populated on every request.

By default the built-in Funq registers everything as a singleton, so when you register an instance e.g:

```
container.Register(new GlobalState());
```

and reference it in your Service:

```
public class HelloWorldService: Service
{
    public GlobalState GlobalState { get; set; }

    public string Get(HelloWorld request)
    {
        return GlobalState.SomeOtherClassInstance;
    }
}
```

behind the scenes it's always injecting the same instance, and in Funq this is very fast since it's literally just retrieving the instance from an in-memory `Dictionary`.

But if for whatever reason you don't like that approach than as a Service is still just a C# class so you can use a static property:

```
public class HelloWorldService: Service
{
    public static GlobalState GlobalState = new GlobalState { ... };

    public string Get(HelloWorld request)
    {
        return GlobalState.SomeOtherClassInstance;
    }
}
```

or a Singleton:

```
public class HelloWorldService: Service
{
    public string Get(HelloWorld request)
    {
        return GlobalState.Instance.SomeOtherClassInstance;
    }
}
```

or however else you want to do it. I recommend using an IOC since it's more testable and consistent with how all other dependences are registered, and I don't really see a good reason not to.

Comment: thanks for your comments but I am confused about how a globalstate instance is retrieved in your first code snippet. Don't I need to access it through tryresolve<T>() from the service base class container? Or does Funq automatically resolve whatever public property I set in the class that derives from Service?

Comment: This is one of the primary functions of an IOC, i.e. it auto-wires/auto-injects the public properties of your services with all your registered dependencies.